# Magento2: How to show multiselect product attribute lable on product detail page

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute, product-detail-page

I am using magento2.3.x

I have created a **dropdown** attribute(product attribute) from admin.

now I have showing this attribute on product page using below code:-

file path:-
**app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.upc_code" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.sku">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getUpcCode</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">upc_code</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">upc_code</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
        <argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="upc_code"</argument>
     </arguments>
</block>
```

Now I have created one more **multiselect** attribute(product attribute) from admin.

I am using the same code above for this attribute to show on product detail page but it showing value of the select option instead of label of the selected options.

Please let me know how to show label of the selected option in multiselect attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update code like below for multiselect attribute.

> For xml file please add like below.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.upc_code2" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.upc_code">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getUpcMulti</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">upc_multi</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">upc_multi</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
        <argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">multiselect</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="upc_multi"</argument>
     </arguments>
</block>
```

> You need to override attribute.phtml file in your theme path. Path
> will be like app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/{{YOUR THEME
> PACKAGE NAME
> HERE}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

Multi select attributes values are saved comma separated in database. So we need to get it's option labels programmatically like below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();

if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}

$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
// if defined as 'none' in layout, do not render
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
    $renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code))
        ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code)
        : '';
} if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'multiselect') {
    $_attributeValue = '';
    $explodeAttributes = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
    $explodeAttributes = explode(',', $explodeAttributes);
    $isAttributeExist = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code);

    if ($isAttributeExist && $isAttributeExist->usesSource()) {
        foreach ($explodeAttributes as $key => $optionId) {
            $_attributeValue .= $isAttributeExist->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId). ',';
        }
    }
    $_attributeValue = trim($_attributeValue, ',');
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue) :?>
<div class="product attribute <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_className) ?>">
    <?php if ($renderLabel) :?>
        <strong class="type"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attributeLabel) ?></strong>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please do changes in code as per you want to show multi select option labels.

**Cheers!**

Comment: thanks for your answer but, when I using your code, it showing multi-select attribute properly but for other attribute it show their code not their label.

Comment: For which attribute type? I have shown you only for multi select attribute type

Comment: other yes/no type. dropdown type and input text type etc...

Comment: This is your different issue. I have provided solution that how you shown selected option label instead of value

Comment: And it's a default magento code , i have just shown you how you need to do for multi select attribute

Comment: Please approve and upvote so other community member will use.

Comment: But why this piece of code change the other type of attributes frontend input?

Comment: It will not change anything except multiselect attribute. https://prnt.sc/1qy5099

Comment: Please check your at_type for other attribute

Comment: If it's still not working show me your code

Comment: yes, still there is issue, once I remove the multiselect code from attribute.phtml, then other type of attribute working fine and multiselect attribute showing attribute code like 45,46.

Comment: Please show me your xml file code

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/DNloYIG.png please check here Screen Size is dropdown type

Comment: I have debugged code here and it is only working with multiselect attribute. Please debug your code and check that if screen_size attribute is going under condition of multiselect or not?